# Can't create WAR in Eclipse Mars 2

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss7.x, war

I have created a NEW->DYNAMIC WEB APPLICATION in Eclipse Mars 2.

For some reason in PROJECT ARCHIVES, when I right click my project->NEW ARCHIVE I can see only JAR but need to create a WAR file.

Comment: Instead of using New Archive, have you tried right clicking and selecting the option 'Export'?

Answer (score 0):

Even though i am using Eclipse Kepler, i believe the way of exporting a .war file is the same. You should right click your project and select the option "Export".

If the "WAR file" submenu doesn't appear right away, then you can select the "Export..." option as showed in the picture below to search for the .war option.

[image]

Then, a window like this one should appear, and you can type for "war" in the filter text or you can search for the Web perspective folder.

[image]

Then you just have to configure the destination folder of you .war file and other preferences, and finish exporting.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a Web project folder and select Export from the pop-up menu. Then select WAR file in the Export window and then select Next.